# r.PostForm and r.Form always empty

Tags: http, go

I have a very strange problem, and i'm either really blind, or this is some kind of a bug. I have the following http.Handler:

```
func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while parsing form data")
        return
    }
    log.Println("Printing r.PostForm:")
    for key, values := range r.PostForm { // range over map
        for _, value := range values { // range over []string
            log.Println(key, value)
        }
    }
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    s := string(b)
    log.Println("Printing body: ",s)
}
```

Now, when sending a PUT-Request to the url binded to this handler with the following FORM-Data:

```
Name=someName
Version=1.0.0
PLanguage=java
GitRepo=someRepo
```

This is ALWAYS the output:

```
Printing r.PostForm:
Printing body: Name=someName&Version=1.0.0&PLanguage=java&GitRepo=someRepo
```

I've been trying to find the cause for like 2 hours already and i just have no idea what the heck is wrong here. There is no error parsing the Form-Data, but the r.PostForm map is always empty (i also tried r.Form, with same result). So for debugging i added the part where i print the body, just to make sure there actually is some data in there - and it is. I would really appreciate any help here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the 'Content-Type' header.

If no header is set "application/octet-stream" is used according to RFC 2616.

Long story short that is a binary format so your body will not be parsed into the `Form`.

Comment: That's what i just also eventually came up with, after trying ParseMultipartForm and getting an error, that the Content-Type is not set. So i added the proper Header and everything seems to work now. But thanks alot for this answer!